# Modules installed with pip don't work after Bookworm upgrade

Tags: debian, python3, pip

I recently upgraded to Debian Bookworm from Bullseye.

I am aware that installation of python packages requires a different method as compared to `pip install <package>`. Therefore, I install new python packages using `pipx` which works well.

**Question:** The packages that have already been installed using `pip` don't work as they were working before. For example, I had installed `pdfCropMargins` using `pip` and have used it extensively before upgrading to Bookworm.

After the upgrade, I get the following error:

```bash
pdf-crop-margins -a 5 pgfmanual.pdf 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/vrgovinda/.local/bin/pdf-crop-margins", line 5, in <module>
    from pdfCropMargins.pdfCropMargins import main
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pdfCropMargins'
```

As per my understanding, I guess that `pipx` is now managing the python packages and is expecting the modules in some other location.

Am I right? If yes, how to resolve this issue?

If No, What is the reason for this error and how to resolve this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python's version compatibility is lousy, even between minor update releases of the language - e.g. if you use pip to install a library module while running python 3.10 then it won't be available when you upgrade to python 3.11. You'll need to **install it again for the new version of python**.

To make the version compatibility problem even worse, python devs & community fetishise this is as a "feature" rather than a bug and have developed a baroquely complicated virtual environment paradigm to work around it - but that's not surprising, since python devs & users tend to view the OS their program is running on as a problem to be avoided/worked-around rather than a useful thing they can benefit from.

Comment: So, I have to re-install all existing python packages?

Comment: only the ones you installed with pip/pipx.  distro packages of python libraries should be fine.

Comment: Oh! That's too much! I have one `whisper` package that pulls in few hundred MBs of dependencies.

Comment: Either reinstall them all or use "the python way", which is to have lots of different versions of python installed and use, e.g. venv, to separate them from each other so that they can all have their own isolated library dirs.    Alternatively, package each of the required libraries for debian in a local repo and then make a whisper package that depends upon them....this is more work but is ultimately the better solution.   Another alternative is to bundle everything required into a chroot or a snap or flatpak image, or a docker image or some other container.

Comment: Can I manually shift some files [created by `pip`] into separate directories inside the `venv` so that `pipx` thinks that those packages have been installed with `pipx`?

Comment: maybe, but why would you want to? it'll take longer to do and be more work and more prone to problems than just using pipx to install it again.

Comment: I had no option than to download few GBs of modules to make whisper work again.. Unfortunate.